# Connect to existing Sesame native datastore

Tags: java, sesame

I've created a Sesame native datastore, and I want to build a SPARQL endpoint with servlet and jsp to query my native RDF data, but I don't know how to connect to my existing native datastore programmtically in Java.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To set up a SPARQL endpoint which you can query remotely, you should set up a [Sesame server](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-server-install). This is a ready-made web application which you can deploy/run in Tomcat or Jetty, and which you can then connect to remotely, e.g. from your JSP/servlet tool. You can either create a new store manually on your Sesame server (e.g. using the Sesame Workbench tool), or programmatically, by using a `RemoteRepositoryManager` to connect to the server. [See this weblog](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/the-repositorymanager/) for details on how to work with `RepositoryManager`s.

Once you have the repository set up on your server, you can connect to it from Java/JSP using a `HTTPRepository` object. See the [user documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view) for details.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I begin to understand it.